remove items from a vector on a condition in Rust
I'm new to Rust. I have code to remove all items in a vector if ISO8601 Week is different from last week.
The code works well.
let mut i = 0;
while i < screenshots.len() {
    let st = screenshots[i].metadata().unwrap().created().unwrap();
    let dt = systemtime_to_iso8601(&st); //<- my function
    if dt.iso_week().week() != ((Local::now().iso_week().week()) - 1) {
        screenshots.remove(i);
        continue;
    }
    i += 1;
}

I have already tried with retain() method, but how to make the closure to take my function systemtime_to_iso8601 to transform SystemTime to DataTime<Local>?
Again, how can I make it if I would like to extract these items in a slice?

What exactly do you want do you want a function that takes a vec of screenshots and returns a vec of screenshots that are 1 week old? (Using retain)

Yes, a function that takes a vec of screenshots and returns a vec of screenshots that are 1 week old
